# How to interpret DESeq results with LRT vs. with Wald's test

Tags: likelihood-ratio, wald-test

I am new to the field of RNA-Seq and wanted to ask for advice concerning the proper use of the two `DESeq()` test options (LRT vs. Wald test).

Briefly, my experimental set up is as follows: I have 30 mice in 5 different treatment groups (n=6/group) and a known batch effect (sequencing was performed at two different days, batch effect confirmed visually via PCA & distance matrix after using limma::removeBatchEffect on the vst-transformed matrix, as referenced in the DESeq2 vignette ([Why after VST are there still batches in the PCA plot?](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/DESeq2/inst/doc/DESeq2.html#why-after-vst-are-there-still-batches-in-the-pca-plot)).
According to your vignette ([Quick Start](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/DESeq2/inst/doc/DESeq2.html#quick-start)), i have defined my design matrix like this:

```
ddsMat <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = countdata,
                             colData  = coldata,
                             design = ~ seq_day + group) #known batch = sequencing days
```

After reading your vignette ([Likelihood ratio test](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/DESeq2/inst/doc/DESeq2.html#likelihood-ratio-test)) and several blog entries in this forum, I have run the `DESeq()` function in two different ways to explore the differences:

```
dds.LRT <- DESeq(ddsFilteredMat, test="LRT", reduced=~seq_day) #LRT
dds<- DESeq(ddsFilteredMat) #Wald
```

As I understood it, the LRT version can be comparable to an ANOVA as it tests for differences across all of the groups, after removing the effect exerted by the batch effect whereas Wald's test is used for direct pairwise comparisons between 2 groups. Consequently, I get the same DEGs, LFC and pvals for any contrast extracted from dds.LRT, since it always compares this:  `LRT p-value: '~ seq_mice_cage + group' vs '~ seq_mice_cage'`.

```r
#extract results
res.groupA_LRT <- results(dds.LRT, contrast = c("group", "A", "control"))
res.groupB_LRT <- results(dds.LRT, contrast = c("group", "B", "control"))
res.groupC_LRT <- results(dds.LRT, contrast = c("group", "C", "control"))
res.groupD_LRT <- results(dds.LRT, contrast = c("group", "D", "control"))

#show top 6 rows per result
data.frame(rbind(cbind(head(res.groupA_LRT), group = rep("A", 6), rank = seq(1,6)), 
                            cbind(head(res.groupB_LRT), group = rep("B", 6), rank = seq(1,6)), 
                            cbind(head(res.groupC_LRT), group = rep("C", 6), rank = seq(1,6)), 
                            cbind(head(res.groupD_LRT), group = rep("D", 6), rank = seq(1,6))))
```

output:

```r
                       baseMean log2FoldChange      lfcSE      stat      pvalue       padj group rank
ENSMUSG00000025902     44.22274    -0.40249365 0.35558183  8.588492 0.072249833 0.22728207     A    1
ENSMUSG00000033845   1310.06464     0.36575419 0.15746631  6.559806 0.161060931 0.36511564     A    2
ENSMUSG00000102275     16.07641     1.30656064 0.79514588  5.777069 0.216426997 0.43092779     A    3
ENSMUSG00000025903   2187.23707     0.14752514 0.14539018  7.719259 0.102420605 0.27909782     A    4
ENSMUSG00000033813    228.33252    -0.24121186 0.19922834 17.043843 0.001895401 0.01960863     A    5
ENSMUSG00000033793   1517.61889    -0.19788049 0.15639653  2.544884 0.636617125 0.77272669     A    6
ENSMUSG00000025902.1   44.22274     0.09838015 0.36613901  8.588492 0.072249833 0.22728207     B    1
ENSMUSG00000033845.1 1310.06464     0.32342520 0.16436483  6.559806 0.161060931 0.36511564     B    2
ENSMUSG00000102275.1   16.07641     2.02343897 0.82375227  5.777069 0.216426997 0.43092779     B    3
ENSMUSG00000025903.1 2187.23707     0.21157088 0.15173852  7.719259 0.102420605 0.27909782     B    4
ENSMUSG00000033813.1  228.33252     0.27254669 0.20653754 17.043843 0.001895401 0.01960863     B    5
ENSMUSG00000033793.1 1517.61889    -0.09809705 0.16316122  2.544884 0.636617125 0.77272669     B    6
ENSMUSG00000025902.2   44.22274     0.23444799 0.36404826  8.588492 0.072249833 0.22728207     C    1
ENSMUSG00000033845.2 1310.06464     0.18044040 0.16541518  6.559806 0.161060931 0.36511564     C    2
ENSMUSG00000102275.2   16.07641     1.42749218 0.81373353  5.777069 0.216426997 0.43092779     C    3
ENSMUSG00000025903.2 2187.23707     0.22914511 0.15270455  7.719259 0.102420605 0.27909782     C    4
ENSMUSG00000033813.2  228.33252    -0.08556367 0.20771886 17.043843 0.001895401 0.01960863     C    5
ENSMUSG00000033793.2 1517.61889    -0.06247866 0.16435798  2.544884 0.636617125 0.77272669     C    6
ENSMUSG00000025902.3   44.22274    -0.16301925 0.23952672  8.588492 0.072249833 0.22728207     D    1
ENSMUSG00000033845.3 1310.06464     0.02632379 0.10753635  6.559806 0.161060931 0.36511564     D    2
ENSMUSG00000102275.3   16.07641     0.62498726 0.49334192  5.777069 0.216426997 0.43092779     D    3
ENSMUSG00000025903.3 2187.23707     0.25842491 0.09947068  7.719259 0.102420605 0.27909782     D    4
ENSMUSG00000033813.3  228.33252    -0.22232786 0.13551622 17.043843 0.001895401 0.01960863     D    5
ENSMUSG00000033793.3 1517.61889    -0.05636333 0.10730159  2.544884 0.636617125 0.77272669     D    6
```

I have defined my contrasts from the Wald-dds object as follows:

```r
res.groupA_Wald <- results(dds, name = "group_A_vs_control")
res.groupB_Wald <- results(dds, name = "group_B_vs_control")
res.groupC_Wald <- results(dds, name = "group_C_vs_control")
res.groupD_Wald <- results(dds, name = "group_D_vs_control")
```

(i) How can I put these two dds results to use in my downstream analyses / what are the reasons for me to choose the LRT output for my set up (5 groups; 4 treatments vs. 1 control)? Since the p.values of the LRT outputs are identical regardless of the contrast (since it only represents ANY significant DEGs between the groups), is it valid to use the LRT-generated p.values as cut-off for the Heatmap/Venn diagram?

(ii) Tying in with the "ANOVA-comparison", is it valid to see the Wald-dds object as a post-hoc test? If so, is there a way to approximate a post-hoc correction similar to Tukey's correction (i.e. less conservative as basic differences have already been confirmed via ANOVA)?

Thank you very much in advance.
Best,
Luise

Answer (score 0):

Quite a bit has been written already about the Wald test and how it compares against a likelihood ratio test, see for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193643/likelihood-ratio-vs-wald-test) (and the links therein), [this page](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqhow-are-the-likelihood-ratio-wald-and-lagrange-multiplier-score-tests-different-andor-similar/), even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test#Alternatives_to_the_Wald_test) has a summary of how they stack up.

Perhaps it's most important to note that these tests are essentially answering the same question. This question is, first specifically and then more intuitively:

- How likely is it that I would have observed this parameter value (or values) under the null hypothesis - usually assuming that the true parameter is zero?
- Is a model that includes this parameter "meaningfully different" from one without, i.e. does this parameter *say* anything about my outcome?

The authors of the vignette seem to make a distinction, possibly because they provide Wald tests only for single parameters (the joint Wald test is computationally a bit more complex) and they draw a parallel to the ANOVA joint F-test, but in truth the **asymptotic** behaviour of either test has been shown to be the same.

Read that bolded word again: Wald and LRT do differ in how they approximate the likelihood function. For an LRT you simply compare the model's total (log-)likelihood versus that of a reduced one, which follows a $\chi^2$ distribution of however many additional degrees of freedom the larger model uses under the null. The major disadvantage is that you have to fit any model twice; full and reduced.

The Wald statistic uses Taylor expansion on the maximum likelihood estimate(s) and its (co)variance, in the one-parameter case this reduces to a Z-test using the parameter MLE and its standard error estimate. Key here is that all of this assumes those estimates are accurate, which is less often the case the smaller your sample. Another complication is that these calculations are not invariant under reparametrization or transformation. You can do all of this quite efficiently from a single model though, so the computational burden is reduced.

In summary, they both answer the same kind of question, but as Wald comes with some stronger assumptions the LRT might be preferred for smaller samples. Both of them break down if your model is misspecified (e.g. lacking relevant predictors or interactions), which might be a bigger concern.

A final remark on your post-hoc analogy: this has everything to do with the threshold of test statistic you use to declare "significance", i.e. my "meaningfully different" above. In both cases this is more a function of the number of test statistics you are generating rather than the method to do so, plus the domain knowledge to assess whether you even need to correct for multiplicity (in exploratory or hypothesis-generating contexts you might not want to).

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer! the links you provided have also been very helpful.